# Simple OpenCV Test only shows first frame

Tags: python, opencv

this simple python script should show continually the webcam video but it only shows the first frame.

```
import cv2

print('cv2 version is ' + str(cv2.getVersionString()))


def capture_config(camera_port=0):
    frame_height = 480
    frame_width = 640

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
    cap.set(3, frame_width)
    cap.set(4, frame_height)
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print('Unable to read camera feed')
        return False
    return cap


cap = capture_config()
while cap:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('captured frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the output is

```
cv2 version is 4.5.1
```

It' on ubuntu 20.03 and python 3.8

any valid reason why the script would only show the first frame ?

Comment: See the documentation of `waitKey`. 0 means wait for key stroke whereas I suppose you want to give 1 (ms) as input.

Comment: @Burak thanks for that. This actually the solution !